# Calculate hash of the BIOS

Tags: memory, x86, dos, ram, bios

I've read that BIOS is mapped to memory at f000:. At f000:fff0 I see JMP to f000:e05b. At e05b another jump. So, the code jumps many times within f000 segment. So, the questions:

1) If I calculate hash of the segment f000:0000 - f000:ffff will I get the hash of the BIOS code?

2) Whether the all bytes of the segment are constant during warm reboot?

Comment: It used to be, 20 years ago.  The BIOS of machines today is around a megabyte in size, a substantial part of it occupied by the machine manufacturer's logo bitmap.  You can calculate the hash of the fake BIOS that your emulator provides, it is a pointless thing to do.

Comment: I working on DOS on VMWARE, seems the BIOS is old.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not necessarily. The BIOS ROM may map to a larger or smaller area than that (though some early BIOSes did map to exactly that memory range).
2. Probably, but again, not necessarily.